# MongoDB Sorting on GeoNear Results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I'm trying to sort the values in the collection "Vehicle" by the text field "condition", although it seems that the sorting is having no effect on the result set.  I believe the syntax is correct, so what would be the cause of this problem?

```
db.Vehicle.aggregate([
{
   $geoNear: {
       near:[26.243640,-80.265397],
       maxDistance: 2500/111.12,
       query: { isActive: true, condition: {$in: ['New','Used']} },
       distanceField: "distance",
       limit: 10
   }
},
{
    $project: {condition: 1, distance: 1}
},
{ 
    $sort: {condition: -1} 
}
])
```

Comment: I believe I found out why.  The $geoNear is limiting the result set so the $sort is only acting on the 10 records retrieved.  Is it possible to do the sorting within the $geoNear or should I use another method to retrieve the results I'm looking for?

Comment: Of course it is working that way the limit in your quey is causing that

Comment: I commented on that already @Sammaye, is there a way to efficiently sort geo located data on both an arbitrary field and distance?

Comment: You could just add the limit at the end, you cannot do the sort the geonear. Even if you could you would probably end up with the same results in terms of performance.